# button com link dentro do form

Tags: javascript, html

Galera tenho um `form` com 2 `button` dentro.
1 e o submit e o outro preciso de colocar um link nele. Ao ser clicado ele não pode enviar o `form` e chamar o link.

Segue meu código:

```
<form name='form' method=post action='link' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

   <button type='submit'>

   <button> link

<form>
```

Comment: Coloca um evento javascript no botão, que altere o valor de `window.href` para o endereço para o qual deseja ir. Lembre-se de que isso não provocará um post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro de um `<form>` botões sem `type` defenido comportam-se como `type="submit"`. Então precisas de ter `type="button"`.

Para fazer ele redirecionar para outra página podes fazer inline assim:

```
<form name='form' method=post action='link' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="window.location='http://google.com'">link</button>
</form>
```

ou com auscultador de evento assim:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.location='http://google.com';
});
```

Tendo no HTML somente:

```
<button type="button">link</button>
```

Comment: Muito bom, resolveu meu problema aqui ;)